# How to export multiple Schemas in same file in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to export two schemas in my model js file and I want use in router js file. I have tried this code below.

**This is my certification.js file(models)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.schema;

const requestCertificationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 userid: { type: String, require: true },
 certName: { type: String, require: true },
 certType: { type: String, require: true },
 examName: { type: String, require: true },
 examYear: { type: String, require: true },
 examIndex: { type: String,  require: true },
 reqDate: {type: String, require: true},
 state: { type: String, require: true}
});

const requestCertification = mongoose.model("requestCertification", requestCertificationSchema);

module.exports.saveRequest = function (newRequestCertification, callback) {
     newRequestCertification.save(callback);
};

const requestStudentstatusSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 studentName: { type: String, require: true },
 admissionNum: { type: String, require: true },
 dateofAdmission: { type: String, require: true },
 currentStatus: { type: String, require: true },
 description: { type: String, require: true },
});

const requestStudentstatus=  mongoose.model("requestStudentstatus", requestStudentstatusSchema);

module.exports = {
  requestCertification: requestCertification,
  requestStudentstatus: requestStudentstatus
}
```

**This is my certification.js file(routes)**

```
const router = express.Router();
const Certification = require('../models/certification');
const config = require('../config/database');

router.post("/requestCert", function (req, res) {
    const newRequest = new requestCertification({
        userid: req.body.userid,
        certName: req.body.certName,
        certType: req.body.certType,
        examName: req.body.examName,
        examYear: req.body.examYear,
        examIndex: req.body.examIndex,
        reqDate:req.body.reqDate,
        state: req.body.state
    });
    console.log(newRequest);
    Certification.requestCertification.saveRequest(newRequest, function (err, request) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ state: false, msg: "Data inserting Unsuccessfull..!" });
        }
        if (request) {
            res.json({ state: true, msg: "Data inserted Successfully..!" });
        }
    });
});
```

When I call this url i have show this error! .

**ReferenceError: requestCertification is not defined**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this code to this one in routes/certification.js

```
const router = express.Router();
const {requestCertification} = require('../models/certification');
const {requestStudentstatus} = require('../models/certification');
const config = require('../config/database');

router.post("/requestCert", function (req, res) {
    const newRequest = new requestCertification({
        userid: req.body.userid,
        certName: req.body.certName,
        certType: req.body.certType,
        examName: req.body.examName,
        examYear: req.body.examYear,
        examIndex: req.body.examIndex,
        reqDate:req.body.reqDate,
        state: req.body.state
    });
    // console.log(newRequest);
    newRequest
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
            res.json({ state: true, msg: "Data inserted Successfully..!" });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            res.json({ state: false, msg: "Data inserting Unsuccessfull..!" });
        })
});
```

and delete the **saveRequest()** function in models/certification.js

Answer (score 2):

```
const router = express.Router();
const { requestCertification, requestStudentstatus } = require('../models/certification');
const config = require('../config/database');

router.post("/requestCert", function (req, res) {
    const newRequest = new requestCertification({
        userid: req.body.userid,
        certName: req.body.certName,
        certType: req.body.certType,
        examName: req.body.examName,
        examYear: req.body.examYear,
        examIndex: req.body.examIndex,
        reqDate: req.body.reqDate,
        state: req.body.state
    });
    // console.log(newRequest);
    newRequest
        .save()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
            res.json({ state: true, msg: "Data inserted Successfully..!" });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            res.json({ state: false, msg: "Data inserting Unsuccessfull..!" });
        })
});
```

Comment: We also can use destructuring method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.